# How to add, modify or delete a property of an object in duktape

Tags: javascript, duktape

I'm trying to write a C function with 1 passed parameter. This parameter has to be an object. And I'd like to modify this object in the C code like this:

```
var modifyObject = function (obj) {
   obj.new_param = 123;
   obj.existing_param2 = 456;;
   delete obj.existing_param3;
}
```

Can someone provide a small example, how to do this?
Of course I can write a C function returning a new object and then write a workaround function in the native JavaScript, but is there any way to do that inside of C?

Answer (score 0):

You would do that using [Duktape property API calls](http://duktape.org/api.html#taglist-property), e.g. as follows:

```
duk_ret_t modify_object(duk_context *ctx) {
    /* argument object is at index 0 */
    duk_push_uint(ctx, 123);                   /* -> stack: [ obj 123 ] */
    duk_put_prop_string(ctx, 0, "new_param");  /* -> stack: [ obj ] */
    duk_push_uint(ctx, 456);
    duk_put_prop_string(ctx, 0, "existing_param2");
    del_prop_string(ctx, 0, "existing_param3");
    return 0;  /* no return value (same as 'return undefined' in Ecmascript) */
}
```

The function would be registered to have a single argument: the object, which will appear at value stack index 0:

```
duk_push_c_function(ctx, modify_object, 1 /*nargs*/);
duk_put_global_string(ctx, "modifyObject");  /* register global binding */
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very helpful and clear now!